# Did José Manuel Moreno indeed score 850 goals in his career?

Tags: football

[José Manuel Moreno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jos%C3%A9_Manuel_Moreno) was a player in Argentina who, in the early 1980s, received an award as the best Argentine player in history (over Alfredo Di Stéfano, the only Super Ballon d'Or player in world history). Di Stéfano himself stated he learned from him and that Moreno was better than him. Journalists who saw him playing make presumptuous claims that he was better than Maradona and Pelé. IFFHS also chose him as the 5th best South American player ever in 2000.

I checked his stats several times and I never saw anything very impressive, yet [an article has recently appeared](https://the100.ru/en/football/jose-manuel-moreno.html) claiming he scored 850 goals. Other articles claimed he scored just 243 goals.

How many goals did José Manuel Moreno score in his career? Did he indeed score 850?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141612/discussion-between-nij-and-pablo).

Answer (score -1):

In the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jos%C3%A9_Manuel_Moreno) about him, it says he scored 224 goals for his clubs and 19 goals for the Argentina national team.

There is an article that claims that he scored 850 goals in 950 games, but there is no supporting information about that claim.

Comment: Up until last month the Wikipedia article itself said 850, due to edits made by the same author as the news report which is being questioned. Without actually using any further sources than WP and the article in question, I don't see how this is useful in any way. Merely repeating the origin of the question is not answering it.

Comment: Now it is in Wikiwand, whatever that is. https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Jos%C3%A9_Manuel_Moreno . The relevance of discussing something which has as reference Wikipedia to me is that those articles are later replicated by dozens of websites.

Comment: Weird, it seems that they removed it from Wikiwand too, or that website is a mere replication of Wikipedia. It still appears in the Google preview of Wikiwand.

Comment: BTW, there are other 2 articles (besides the original russian domain one) claiming the same, probably replicated from the same source, but no one can confirm that yet. https://www.calendarz.com/on-this-day/august/3/jose-manuel-moreno https://persona.rin.ru/eng/view/f/0/34666/moreno-jose-manuel . The other possibility is that those 850 goals are including friendly games such as claims of 1283 goals made by Pelé, which officially actually were 767.

Comment: Or of course, the most obvious and most likely answer: the writer of the article made it up entirely, like their other work suggests, and the correct number is around 240, like every other source has consistently figured.